# Using PLL to generate clock signal superior to 400Mhz on MAX10 FPGA

Tags: vhdl, clock, intel-fpga

I'm using 10M50 FPGA to read data from a camera via MIPI-CSI2, but the clock I have on the board can't operate fast enough. So right now i'm trying to use the PLL to generate faster clock signal.

I'm using the following code to test if the clock signal generated is correct, by manually setting the v1 variable so my led blink every second. In this example the PLL (generated by the ALTPLL wizard from the Quartus IP Catalog) is set to receive a 100MHz clock signal and should display a 400MHz clock signal however nothing happens.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

LIBRARY altera_mf;
USE altera_mf.all;

--   debut entity     --

entity test is 
    port(
        CLK : in std_logic;
        LED0 : out std_logic     -- leds are ON for '0' and OFF for '1'
    );
end test;


-- debut architecture --

architecture test_led of test is 
signal s_led0 : std_logic :='1';
signal c0 : std_logic;

component pll400
    port(   inclk0      : IN STD_LOGIC  := '0';
            c0      : OUT STD_LOGIC 
    );
end component;

begin

clk1:pll400
    port map(inclk0 => CLK, 
                c0 => c0
    );

p:process(c0,s_led0)
variable v1 : integer range 0 to 800000000 :=0;
begin               
    if c0'event and c0 = '1' then
        v1 := v1 + 1;       
        if v1 = 400000000 then
            s_led0 <='0';   
        end if; 
        if v1 = 800000000 then
            s_led0 <='1';
            v1 := 0;
        end if;
    end if;

LED0 <= s_led0;
end process;    
end test_led;
```

I was able to use this to generate and test signal up to 320MHz, but it doesn't seem to be able to go higher, though I haven't find any documentation saying it was impossible. (my sources are mostly the 10M50 user guide and Intel Max10 Clocking and PLL User guide)

I did also try to use PLLs in cascade, inputting the output clock of a 100 -> 200Mhz PLL into a 200 -> 400MHz PLL but i had the same result, meaning my led wouldn't blink.

So is there something I'm missing or is it impossible to generate such signal with my current board ?

Edit : datasheet I am using as references :
[MAX10 Clocking and PLL](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/archives/ug-m10-clkpll-16.0.pdf)
[10M50 User Guide](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/612/10M50_evaluation_board_userguide-1304871.pdf)

Comment: This question is more at home in the electronics section. But I suspect you will get the same answer there: Normally the maximum frequency of a PLL is in the datasheet. I would be very astonished if it is not in there. But knowing FPGAs it might take a while to find the **right** datasheet.

Comment: The 10M datasheet says the -8 speed grade part should reach 402 MHz but also states performance can be limited by reference clock jitter. Your question does not provide enough information nor appears to relate to programming. (You could expect the output jitter of a first PLL to exceed the jitter limit for the input to the second. See the datasheet.)

Comment: @Oldfart It should be in the electonics section you're right, sorry about that, this is my first question here. I found in the datasheet that the maximum VCO frequency is 1300MHz (I'll link it in the post) but I don't know if that is usable.

Comment: @user1155120 Sorry I tried to be as concise as possible, could you tell me what you would need to know so I can edit the post ? Or should I recreate it in the electronics section ?
Thank you both

Comment: See the [10M datasheet](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/m10_datasheet.pdf). The FPGA board User Guide specifies a -6 speed grade (in the device part number). [Si5338 datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si5338.pdf). The proper place for this question may be [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl+intel-fpga).

Answer (score 1):

Is your design timing-constraited? What does the timing report says?

Maybe it's not the PLL, but the fabric itself is slow enough to work at higher frequencies. You have some 30-bit comparators and a 30-bit adder working single-clock at 400 Mhz, that's pretty harsh for MAX10.
You should consider increasing adder pipelining, this will boost its freq performance, but it will only yield result one time per 2 or 3 or more clock cycles, so you will need an additional latch at its output.

As for the comparators, they might not be needed at all if you switch to the powers of 2 as your limits. Set v1 as a 31-bit value, and use a 31th bit of v1 for s_led0, this will give you another divide ratio, but will be much simpler logic-wise. And you won't need to reset v1 as well - the adder will wrap-around it automatically.